# Making Sodium Citrate

Tags: acid-base, everyday-chemistry

I've been trying to make Sodium Citrate and I've seen online people saying just react sodium bicarbonate with citric acid in water (with correct ratios) and boil off/remove water once the reaction has ceased.
I've also seen online that some people suggest to use sodium carbonate instead.
I thought I would ask here as I assume at some point the bicarbonate would turn to carbonate when reacted/exposed to the heat anyway by releasing hydrogen and carbon dioxide but I'm not a chemistry guy so if anyone knows which is better or which would result in more fool proof way, please let me know!
Thanks!

Comment: The problem is that the 3rd acidic  H of citric acid has about the same acidity as CO2(aq), so there is more or less balanced equilibrium  $\ce{HCitr^2- + HCO3- <=> Citr^3- + CO2 + H2O}$. Boiling helps, if done properly, but Na2CO3 ensures the stoichiometry is achieved.

Comment: Thanks. I shall use sodium carbonate/Na2CO3 then. Cheers for your help.